# .htaccess 301 redirect with regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2

I need to update my .htaccess file to redirect permanently all URLs from `http://example.com/pages/5604/article/something/?page=299` to `http://example.com/pages/5604/article/`. Here is my implementation (which sadly doesn't work):

`RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)/(.*)/something/\?page=(.*) /pages/$1/$2 [R=301,L]`

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QUERY_STRING` is not in the url that is matched, you'll have to match that separately in a `RewriteCond`. Something like (untested):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*) 
# Apache >=  2.4
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)/(.*)/something/ /pages/$1/$2 [R=301,L,QSD]
# Apache <  2.4 
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)/(.*)/something/ /pages/$1/$2? [R=301,L]
```

If you need the value after `page=` in your `RewriteRule`, you can use `%1` in the same way you use `$1` (matches in `RewriteCond`'s are `%N`, in `RewriteRule` `$N`)

Comment: This is a very good start (Thank You!), but it still appends `?page=(.*)`. How can I get rid of that too?

Comment: Hm, this is new to me, but the [`QSD` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) seems to be needed, learned something today too ;)

Comment: Oh, and if you are using < 2.4: append a `?` instead.